# use go 1.13 build a dll under windows

Tags: windows, go, cgo

I make a simple Go file that exports a function

```
package main

import "C"
import "fmt"

//export PrintBye
func PrintBye() {
    fmt.Println("From DLL: Bye!")
}

func main() {
    // Need a main function to make CGO compile package as C shared library
}
```

and build it

go build -buildmode=c-shared main.go

have a problem

> ## command-line-arguments
>
> C:\Program Files\GO\pkg\tool\windows_amd64\link.exe: running gcc failed: exit status 1
>   C:\Users****\AppData\Local\Temp\go-link-293444627\go.o: file not recognized: file format not recognized
>   collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

in the MinGW ,I install some basic package

```
mingw-developer-toolkit-bin
mingw32-base-bin
mingw32-gcc-g++-bin
mingw32-gcc-objc-bin
msys-base-bin
```

Comment: I find it suspicious that your Go toolset appears to specifically call a linker of the `windows/amd64` architecture while your MinGW packages appear to be 32-bit.
You might need http://mingw-w64.org or [TDM64](http://tdm-gcc.tdragon.net).

Comment: You could also try building the project after having run `set GOARCH=386` in your console window—to make the Go toolchain cross-compile the binary for the 32-bit arch. If that will work, the problem is definitely with 32 vs 64 bit.

Comment: Thank you both，I install mingw-w64 and fix this problem